# Noteworthy font introduced in iOS 4.3 and fallback to other font on < 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, fonts

I am creating an application that is intended to run on 4.2+ ios devices. For aesthetic reasons, by default I would like to use Noteworthy font that has replaced Chalkboard font since iOS 4.3.
I assume that in iOS 4.2 Noteworthy font is not available and I have to fallback to another font if user is running this version of the system? What is the best approach to do the fallback?
Should i use

```
(UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

and check for nil return value?

Can I use noteworthy in my xib file or would doing so crash 4.2 device?

Comment: I think i might have misread and apple might have replaced the font only in Notes application. It would make sense as introducing a breaking change like this would be a silly move from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `fontWithName:size:` returns nil, or you can examine the array returned by `[UIFont familyNames]`.

I don't know for sure if you will crash on 4.2, but the [*UILabel Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW5) says this:

> The value for the property can only be set to a non-nil value; setting
>   this property to nil raises an exception.

So a crash seems likely.

Comment: I am using UITextView and setting nil doesn't seem to crash the app, but that is a good point.